# Generating a Bezier Square in Multiple Steps

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I can generate a square with this standard code.

```
func drawSquare() {
    let width:CGFloat = 100
    var square = UIBezierPath()
    square.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: width))
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: width))
    square.lineWidth = 5
    square.closePath()
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    square.stroke()
}
```

However, if I want to draw each addLineToPoint() segment in two steps, my square no longer draws correctly.

```
func drawSquare2Steps() {
    let width:CGFloat = 200
    let mult:CGFloat = 2
    var square = UIBezierPath()
    square.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)) // 1
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0)) // 2
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100)) // 3
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)) // 4
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)) // 5
    square.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200)) //6

    square.lineWidth = 5
    square.closePath() // 7
    UIColor.orangeColor().setStroke()
    square.stroke()
}
```

Here's the path that I see:

[image]

I tried to describe this function in this image:

[image]

My final goal isn't to draw a square but a more complicated path.  The square simply illustrates the problem with my complex path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong except that your view size is (100, 100) but the square size is (200,200), so you don't see the whole square.